# Python code for string equal not working for python

Tags: python

i can not get My python code to work it does not replay after i give a answer

```
Weight = input("Weight: ")
 lbsorkg = input("(L)bs or (K)g: ")
if lbsorkg.upper == "K":
     FinalPounds = float(Weight) * 2.205
     print(f"You are {FinalPounds} pounds")
```

And I get this

```
Weight: 12
(L)bs or (K)g: k
```

Please help me slove this issue

Comment: You need to call the method `lbsorkg.upper()`

Comment: K is not equal to k

Comment: `.upper` is a method, not a property

Comment: @balderman more like `<built-in method upper of str object at 0x000001F860F540D8>
` is not equal to `'K'`, which is what you get if you don't use the parentheses when you call the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the strings' attribute `upper`, which is not a simple attribute but an instance function.
You must call it, like this:

```
>>> "k".upper()
'K'
```

---

In your case, you should call `lbsorkg.upper()`, like this:

```
if lbsorkg.upper() == 'K':
    ...
```

---

I don't understand what's wrong with this.

Comment: Sorry But its wrong

Comment: what's wrong with this?

Comment: the correct is to make it a method not vairable.lower u need vairable.lower()

Comment: *it's exactly what i wrote...

Comment: i was bad at understanding